# Is there a way to programmatically update an App Setting in an Azure Function slot?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I need to update a Function app setting in a slot programmatically, ideally using Powershell Az module or az cli. I can see the function `Update-AzFunctionAppSetting` exists but as far as I can see it's not possible to use it on a slot.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use az cli to update slot app settings:

```
az functionapp config appsettings set --name MyFunctionApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup --slot MySlot --slot-settings "Name1=Value1"
```

Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/functionapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az_functionapp_config_appsettings_set for details.